# Como funciona a adaptação a diferentes resoluções no Android?

Tags: android, resolução-de-tela, app

No html por exemplo, os objetos podem(as vezes sem nenhum código especial) se adaptar ao tamanho da janela, como por exemplo ao colocar duas imagens de tamanho fixo, se diminuir a janela uma vai para a linha de baixo.

Mas e em um App Android? Os elementos são fixos? Isso varia? Preciso fazer um app diferente para cada resolução ou tamanho de tela?

Ainda não programo para Android, mas gostaria de saber qual o conceito das Apps nesse sentido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Resposta:

A adaptação para diferentes resoluções do [android](/questions/tagged/android) consiste em: Valores relativos à um `LinearLayout` que seriam os Pesos(`android:layout_weight`).

## Explicação:

Você pode atribuir a propriedade `android:layout_weight` em seus elementos XML, que seria como se fosse um peso(bem dizer porcentagem) que é distribuído de acordo com o valor desta propriedade em todos os elementos que estão relativos ao seu `LinearLayout`, seria uma soma de todos os `Weight`'s que estão declarados em `Elementos` dentro do seu `LinearLayout` que por si só tem um `WeightSum` que é uma propriedade que diz qual é o valor máximo(`100%`) permitido aos seus filhos. Por padrão o valor do `WeightSum` é `1`.

A propriedade em sí do `WeightSum` que é o padrão de peso total do `LinearLayout` seria `android:weightSum=x` onde `x` seria o valor do weight (que pode ser decimal).

A propriedade em sí do `Layout Weight` que é o valor do peso de um elemento filho do  `LinearLayout` seria `android:layout_weight=x` onde `x` seria o valor do weight (que pode ser decimal).

## Exemplo:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:weightSum="1" <!-- aqui está o weightSum -->
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/to" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/subject" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" <!-- aqui está o weight -->
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

## Resultado:

[image: exemplo weight]

## Observações:

No `EditText` da Mensagem você não tem valores em `dp` absolutos para o height(altura), você só tem `android:layout_weight="1"` que seria o peso do tal elemento.

Se você olhar em todos os elementos filhos do `LinearLayout`, vai perceber que o único elemento que contém weight(peso) seria o `EditText` da Mensagem, por isso a soma de todos os weight's seria `1`. Porém se houvesse outro elemento com `1` de weight também, o weight total seria `2` e iria ultrapassar o limite padrão do `WeightSum` do `LinearLayout` que seria `1`.

Porém se você tiver um `WeightSum` de `10`, por exemplo, você poderia ter `10` elementos filhos contendo `android:layout_weight=1` cada um, sendo assim cada elemento teria `10%` do tamanho total.

## Observação muito importante:

Você pode estar se perguntando: Ok, mas onde que eu informo se o weight é pra altura ou pra largura??

A resposta é: Isso é estritamente vinculado ao `Orientation` do seu `LinearLayout` que seria esta propriedade:

```xml
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Da qual você pode notar que está declarada no `LinearLayout` de exemplo acima, porém se ele fosse **horizontal** os weight's seriam aplicados na horizontal apenas.

## [Referência](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)

Comment: Então, utilizando essas propriedades, os elementos poderiam se adaptar a qualquer tamanho de tela?

Comment: Sim. Podem se adaptar, porém uma imagem por exemplo não pode, porque você teria que ter arquivos diferentes para cada "tipo" de resolução, ok? aí é outra coisa.

Comment: Sua resposta me fez entender o que eu queria, mas ela não está muito objetiva em relação as perguntas que foram feitas, por isso não vou marcar como resposta ainda. Creio que se você melhorar, vai ficar mais fácil a compreesão para outros usuários interessados na pergunta.

Comment: Agora está melhor @JoaoPaulo ? :)

Comment: Sim, mas sem querer ser chato e já sendo, a sua resposta está mais técnica, e isso é ótimo. Mas como eu disse ainda não programo para Android e estava em busca do conceito. Que pelo que interpretei é que existem elementos que podem ter propriedades que se adaptam a resolução do celular e outros não. E que não é preciso fazer diversos layouts para tamanhos diferentes de tela.

Comment: Exatamente, não é preciso fazer diversos layouts, apenas um só utilizando `weight` funciona igual em todas as resoluções de todos os celulares :) porem se você fazer sem `weight` não vai funcionar igual em todos os celulares.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando LinearLayout. Uma observação De como utilizar imagens no android apanhei ja bastante com isso agora utilizo esse conceito, não coloca o tamanho que você queira que o componente fica na tela, exemplo. coloca o campo usuario no centro vertical e horizontal. apartir dae coloco a distancia que ele deve manter do canto direito ou esquerdo do celular. ou como está estabeler o tamanho dele de acordo com a margem direita e esquerda da tela que ae conforme o tamanha ta tela a imagem altera e altera o comprimento dos campos mantendo a estética
exemplo se eu especificar a imagem no tamanho 220x90 ela tera esse comprimento em todos o tamanho de tela,com isso o android vem com 4 pasta para essas imagens, so colocar as imagens com o mesmo nome em cada pasta ae android especifica qual a melhor resolução para a tela que esta sendo aberta
drawable -hdpi       dimensão  0.75
drawable-mdpi                  1
drawable-xhdpi                 1.5 
drawable-xxhdpi                2.0

Imagebutton
ImageView
utilize a propriedade android:src="@drawable/nome_da_imagem"