# Tamanho de colunas em um GridView em Android

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho em meu projeto android um gridview que eu defino da seguinte forma:

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/grid1"
android:layout_width="600dp"      
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
android:numColumns="5"
android:columnWidth="120dp"
android:gravity="center"/>
```

Eu gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de definir o tamanho do gridview para 100% da tela e o tamanho de 20% da tela para cada coluna.

Comment: O teu layout está com altura de 100% bem como o `gridview` ? E o que precisas é de definir as colunas para 20% de altura, é isso?

Comment: Não o que pretendo é 20% de largura para cada coluna

Comment: Presumo que o que procuras será [gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setStretchMode%28int%29) dado teres um número fixo de colunas, só precisas indicar que devem ocupar toda a largura mediante o tamanho disponível.

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez que estás a indicar o número de colunas, podes fazer uso de [`android:stretchMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android%3astretchMode) para indicar que pretendes que todas as colunas tenham a mesma largura em função do espaço:

> Defines how columns should stretch to fill the available empty space, if any.

Que traduzido:

> Define como as colunas se devem esticar para preencher o espaço vazio disponível que possa existir.

Precisas de utilizar a constante `columnWidth` que indica que cada coluna é esticada por igual:

```
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
```

No teu código:

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/grid1"
android:layout_width="600dp"      
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
android:numColumns="5"
android:columnWidth="120dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"/>
```

---

<sup>Para versão não XML, ver [gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setStretchMode%28int%29) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A solução **é mais simples do que parece**:

**Primeiro:** Você deve checar se o `LinearLayout` que você está envolvendo a sua `GridView` está com `android:orientation="horizontal"`, se não estiver você deve colocar.
Ps: Se você não estiver envolvendo-a em um `LinearLayout`(que seria fora do padrão) você **deve** envolver.

**Segundo:** Você pode apenas com um único atributo resolver seu problema, que seria o `android:layout_weight="1"`

Você pode se perguntar *"tá mas como que ficou 20% o tamanho de cada coluna se você nem setou nada"* - e então eu te respondo: Colocando Weight 1 ela automaticamente se distribui em 5 itens por "linha" ou seja na horizontal teremos sempre 5 colunas, e se você for ver:

`(10/5itens) = 2 ----> 2 = 20% ----> 10 = 100%`

Ficando desta forma:

```xml
<GridView android:id="@+id/grid1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"      
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
android:numColumns="5"
android:columnWidth="120dp"
android:gravity="center"/>
```

## Resultado:

[image: GridView]

**Obs:** Note que eu coloquei *Width 0*, porque quando trabalhamos com Weight, devemos setar o tamanho da orientação para 0, ou seja se o orientation do LinearLayout pai estivesse como vertical, o weight seria aplicado na vertical, então o Height que deveria ser 0.

### Para você entender melhor, recomendo a leitura da [minha resposta em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6287/3082)